# Session Flask doesn't set cookies on browser, Postman does

Tags: javascript, python, nginx, flask, cookies

I'm trying to use the session from Flask on a REST API to set a Cookie on browser. When requesting the API with Postman, the Cookie is correctly set, but when I try to call the route with Javascript on a NGINX Web Server, Cookies dont seem to work.

My application is configured using:

**app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, session, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.secret_key = "0552bcfda3f98940bfecd53296d12c65"

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'], endpoint='login')
def login():
    session['exists'] = 'yes'
    return jsonify({'message': 'logged'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8000, debug=True)
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="btn-submit" type="submit"><br>
    <script>

    var buttonSubmit = document.querySelector('#btn-submit')

    buttonSubmit.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:8000/login", true)
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
        request.send()
    })
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/app:**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    location / {
    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';

        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
        }
    if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
        }
    if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
        }
    root /home/Documents/Python/;
    index index.html;
    }
    location /app {
    rewrite ^/app/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP ip_address;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49712385/flask-session-not-persisting-postman-works-javascript-doesnt

Comment: @ngShravil.py Thanks for the comment! Unfortunately, I've already tried that solution but it didn't work

Comment: @ThiagoBenine Hello, were you able to come up with a solution?